# How create two Variable and filter with map_dbl

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following data

```
Year    <- c("2021","2021","2021","2021","2021","2021")
Month   <- c("8","8","8","8","8","8")
Day <- c("10","15","18","20","22","25")
Hour <- c("171110","171138","174247","183542","190156","190236")
Id_Type <-  c("2","2","1","","1","")
Code_Intersecction <- c("340","","","210","750","980")

Data = data.frame(Year,Month,Day,Hour,Id_Type,Code_Intersecction)
```

I need to count the amount of "" that exists in the base, for that I use the following if it is greater than 5% it takes the value of 1 otherwise 0

```
Data_Null = as.data.frame(purrr::map_dbl(Data, .f = function(x){ifelse(round(sum(x == '')/nrow(Data)*100L,3) >= 5, 1, 0)}))
colnames(Data_Null) = "Null"
```

the problem comes when I see the data frame it only takes me one column and not 2; names and value 0/1

[image]

How can I make it appear as follows

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `colMeans` on a logical matrix in `base R`, convert the named vector to a two column data.frame with `stack`

```
stack(+(colMeans(Data == "") > 0.05))[2:1]
```

**Explanation** - `Data == ""` returns a logical matrix, `colMeans` get the `mean` of the logical vector for each column (which would be the percentage (`*100`) of TRUE values), then convert to logical vector by comparing with `0.05` (5 percent).  The logical can be coeced to binary with either (`+`) or use `as.integer`.  The output of `colMeans` is a named `vector`, which remains as such.  `stack` converts the logical named vector to a two column data.frame.  Indexing (`[2:1]`) will reorder the columns i.e. 2nd column appears first, followed by first column.

-output

```
                 ind values
1               Year      0
2              Month      0
3                Day      0
4               Hour      0
5            Id_Type      1
6 Code_Intersecction      1
```

---

With `tidyverse`, the equivalent is `enframe` (from `tibble`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
map(Data, ~ +(round(mean(.x == ""), 3) * 100 >= 5)) %>%
  enframe(name = 'Variables') %>%
  unnest(value)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Variables          value
  <chr>              <int>
1 Year                   0
2 Month                  0
3 Day                    0
4 Hour                   0
5 Id_Type                1
6 Code_Intersecction     1
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the + sign means in the code stack(+(colMeans(Data == "") > 0.05))[2:1]

Answer (score 2):

Use `tibble:rownames_to_column`:

```r
tibble::rownames_to_column(Data_Null, var ="Variables")

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Variables           Null
  <chr>              <dbl>
1 Year                   0
2 Month                  0
3 Day                    0
4 Hour                   0
5 Id_Type                1
6 Code_Intersecction     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```
Data$Variables <- rownames(Data)
```

Comment: There's a couple more steps you'll probably want to do: change the order of columns, since this appends the new column as the last column, and drop the row names, as they're no longer included in the OP's desired output